# Is there a way to refer to fields in Angular 12 when you don't know the name of them?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a very general table component that can be reused for other Angular projects with different structures in the future. My idea was to get an Input of a data array into the component, but I don't particularly want to restrict the datatype in case other models will be used in the future. Because of this, I don't know how to extract the different fields from the datatype, since I can't know what the name of it might be.

I have tried getting a separate input of the field names, but I don't really know how to use it in combination with the actual array in the template; besides, I feel like the extra step of creating a separate array with the type fields would be an unnecessary extra step. The project is running on Angular 12.
Does anyone have any ideas, or do I simply need to rethink?

Comment: Creating a generic table sounds like a good idea if you have to use a table several times. You could create a component which has 1 input, data. Initialize your table and get the columns names by calling Object.keys on your data property then save the result in an array and use *ngFor to create the columns in the HTML. No need to know  columns name from start, but you could add a new property to exclude columns though.

Comment: @Lorenzo thank you! I had to make a few modifications in other parts of my program as well, but this helped a lot! :)